# variable from loop iteration 0 passed to next loop etc

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, for-loop

Firstly, apologies for my poor Pythoning skills - have come to Python from being a mediocre IDL user so I know I'm not doing things in the best way.

Here's the problem, I am running an analysis over a loop of files. I am generating an image called so2c.  For this image, I want to find the difference between the image and the one previous to it, therefore only want to do this on the loop after the first one.  The following code however throws up the error "NameError: global name 'so2dat' is not defined".  I previously had the code working by storing all the images into one massive numpy array and then finding the difference. However, over about 150 images I was running out of memory.  Help appreciated :)

```
for files in files_list:

    fname1 = files
    .....do some more processing to generate an image array ([512,644]) called so2c

    if files_list.index(files)==0: 
        so2dat=so2c
        timea=times2
    else:
        sdiff= so2c-so2dat
        tdiff= times2-timea
        so2dat=so2c
        timea=times2
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is pretty simple. You are defining `so2dat` in your `if` block, and you are using it in your `else` block. You can only enter one block, and not the other, per iteration. So if you enter your `else` block before you enter your `if` block you will not have performed the definition of `so2dat` in your `if` block.

Check out a super-simple example:

```
>>> for word in "foo bar baz".split():
        if word[0] == 'f':
            hello = "hello"
        else:
            print hello

hello
hello
>>> for word in "foo bar baz".split():
        if word[0] == 'b':
            blah = "blah"
        else:
            print blah

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#25>", line 5, in <module>
    print blah
NameError: name 'blah' is not defined
```

No worries if you enter the `if` block first, but if you enter the `else` block first, you get that `NameError`.

Thinking about it, if you are trying to make sure that you enter the `if` block only on your first iteration, you could use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#enumerate) and use the count part of that to check if you are on the very first iteration. Or, you could do something like this (just remove the first iteration from the loop, do it separately, and then loop over a slice of the rest of your `files_list`):

```
so2dat, timea = do_some_processing_on(files_list[0])
for files in files_list[1:]:
    fname1 = files
    so2c, times2 = do_some_processing_on(fname1)
    # what have you
    sdiff= so2c-so2dat
    tdiff= times2-timea
    so2dat=so2c
    timea=times2
```

Comment: Thanks - have done it the loop way. This seems more IDL-ish to me :) Thansk all for responses, very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're trying to use a variable before you define it.

```
    so2dat=so2c
    timea=times2
else:
    # where does it get defined for use here?
    sdiff= so2c-so2dat
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize so2dat before entering the `if` block:

```
....
so2dat=so2c
if files_list.index(files)==0: 
    so2dat=so2c
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to declare the variable outside of your loop and then see whether it has already been set. Simplified example:

```
lastImage = None
for image in images:
    # do stuff
    if lastImage is not None:
        # compare images
    lastImage = image
```